# send array in link php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to send multiple id in php link my code is :

```
$id_resa = array($ligne['id_resa']);
echo $query = http_build_query(array('id_resa' => $id_resa));
```

the result of echo is :`id_resa%5B0%5D=1205 id_resa%5B0%5D=1204` so its work and its give me two id, but when i use it in link outside the while function i get in the link just the last id.

my link code is :

```
 <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tbody>

            <tr>



          <td><center><a target="blank" href="imprimer.php?id_client=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_client'];?>&agence=<?php echo $_REQUEST['agence'];?>&date=<?php echo $_REQUEST['date'];?>&id_facture=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_facture'];?>&type_paiement=<?php echo $_REQUEST['type_paiement'];?>&id_resa=<?php echo $query;?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Imprimer Facture</button></a></center>
          </td>
          </tr>

             </tbody>

                    </table>
```

is there any method to have this two id in the link together?

Comment: give your query string variables unique names, e.g. : `id_resa0`, `id_resa1` etc.

Comment: i can't do this because i dont know how many id_resa i have its depend on the database

Comment: @MaryamAit can you write here how IDs are stored in DB or how it could be taken into PHP script?

Comment: right now there is 5 id but the user can add more

Answer (score 0):

your `$ligne['id_resa']` is NOT an array, so you have to assign your id_resa column into another array then you can use `implode(',', $id_resa_Array)`  to obtain a comma separated list of his values. You can also use the pipe | or - or any other chars you prefer to separate ids.
Then remove `http_build_query` and pass the ids strings into your URL string

```
$id_resa_Array = array_column($ligne,'id_resa');
print_r($id_resa_Array);

$id_resa = implode(',',$id_resa_Array);

<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>
             <center>
                <a target="blank" href="imprimer.php?id_client=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_client'];?>&agence=<?php echo $_REQUEST['agence'];?>&date=<?php echo $_REQUEST['date'];?>&id_facture=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id_facture'];?>&type_paiement=<?php echo $_REQUEST['type_paiement'];?>&id_resa=<?php echo $id_resa;?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Imprimer Facture</button></a>
             </center>
          </td>
       </tr>

    </tbody>

 </table>
```

obviously to reuse the ids in PHP you have to explode them with `explode(',',$_GET['id_resa']);`

but the risk is the querystring becomes too long, if so you should think to perform a POST request instead

Comment: but in the database each id is in a separate line

Comment: this is precisely the node, with implode() you merge all DB rows into a string, with explode() you get separated values again

Comment: i get this error : Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\Hotel\facture_detail.php on line 252

Comment: is your $ligne['id_resa'] an array of id?.  here the official documentation [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: no its not an array ligne['id_resa'] can just fetch all the id_resa in the database

Comment: what  var_dump($ligne['id_resa']) prints on screen?

Comment: string(4) "1205" string(4) "1204"

Comment: ok try passing only $ligne into implode()  `$id_resa = implode(',',$ligne);` then  var_dump($id_resa) what shown? you shoud get somthing like this string(9) "1205,1024"

Comment: string(161) "123,123,112,112,5,5,-1,-1,147,147,1,1,1,1,4,4,1,1,2019-10-01,2019-10-01,2019-10-16,2019-10-16,2019-10-18,2019-10-18,2,2,0,0,267,267,27,27,558,558,64,64,1205,1205" string(161) "127,127,112,112,2,2,-1,-1,120,120,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2019-10-01,2019-10-01,2019-10-16,2019-10-16,2019-10-18,2019-10-18,2,2,0,0,218,218,22,22,756,756,16,16,1204,1204"

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your example result: `id_resa%5B0%5D=1205 id_resa%5B0%5D=1204`
I think there is some problem with indexes because of there are two `0` indexes (`id_resa[0]=1205 id_resa[0]=1204`).

But with this code the example is better for me:

```php
$id_resa = array(
    1205,
    1204,
);
$query = http_build_query(array('id_resa' => $id_resa));
var_dump($query);
```

output:

```
string(39) "id_resa%5B0%5D=1205&id_resa%5B1%5D=1204"
```

So I think there is a problem somewhere the query build because of there are two `0` index in the array. :o

But you need to avoid sending much data through http GET method because their limit. [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: the problem is that i don't how many id_resa i will get its depend on the database this is why i do : id_resa = $ligne['id_resa'];